# Possible to connect Eclipse/RAD/WebSphere dev to a VM or remote computer?

Tags: eclipse, virtual-machine, vmware, ibm-rad

I am developing a corporate web application and we wish to test out various versions of IE without relying on F12 tools or having multiple physical machines. Because of this, I felt it would be a great idea to run the WinIE VM (VirtualBox, VMWare) as a guest on a Win7 host. We are using VMWare.

Does anyone know if RAD/Eclipse allows incoming network connections? I cannot get this to work on our corporate LAN. I can browse the Internet fine in the VM. I have tried the local routing (192.***) or the dedicated IP address for the host system. I tried browsing from a networked computer and cannot reach it. We can ping each other (VM or physical computer), but just cannot serve up the web app.

Anyone with any ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: This has nothing to do with RAD/Eclipse allowing "incoming connections". What you need is WAS to accept incoming connections. But it's unclear what it is that you're trying to do. Are you running WAS inside of a VM? or are you running WAS on the host, and trying to access WAS from within a VM?

Comment: Can you provide more details? What exactly do you mean by Web App? What exactly do you mean by 'serve up the web app'?